# css outline error in firefox on li and hidden div

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a horizontal list in which i am placing div's which are hidden until hovered over. To keep the dimensions (the hidden divs are the width of the menu) i am using `outline: 2px solid black;` , this works in ie and chrome, it outlines the li item but in firefox it outlines the entire `ul` item including the hidden div.

Does anyone know of a workaround for this or do i have a conflict for firefox outline?

css:

```
#marketmenu ul li{
   display: block;
   float: left;
   position: relative;
   cursor: pointer !important;
   z-index: inherit;
   font-size: 16px;
   padding-top: 2px;
   font-weight: bolder;
   width: 15%;
   height: 40px;
   text-align: center;
   background: white;
   outline: 2px solid black;   
}


#marketmenu ul li div {
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   top: 98%;
   width: 600%;
   background: #ffffff;
   height: 200px;
   opacity: 0;
   visibility: hidden;
   overflow: hidden;
   z-index: 9;
   -moz-border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
   -webkit-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
   -moz-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
   -o-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
   -ms-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
   transition: all .3s ease .15s;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="mheader-container"> 

    <div id="logo" class="clearfix">
        <a href="#"><img src="..."></a>
    </div>

    <div class="userstatus">
    <a href="#" class="mlogbuttons"><span class="icon-user-add"></span> Create an account</a>
    <a href="#" class="mlogbuttons"><span class="icon-user"></span> Log in</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="market_navigation" class="market_navigation clearfix">
        <div id="marketmenu">
            <ul>
                <li>one<div class="menudrop"></div></li>
                <li>two<div class="menudrop"></div></li>
                <li>three<div class="menudrop"></div></li>
                <li>four<div class="menudrop"></div></li>
                <li>five<div class="menudrop"></div></li>
                <li>six<div class="menudrop"></div></li>
            </ul>

        </div>      
</div>
```

jsfiddle (remember its only in firefox there is a issue, renders fine in ie/chrome)
http://jsfiddle.net/ww2rkexd/1/

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok this isnt pretty but it works....basically set a background of the border color and then a overlay div with the correct color. The dropdown div remains in proportion to the parent menu.

**jsfiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/dheffernan/pas1fqcp/

**HTML**

```
<div id="market_navigation" class="market_navigation clearfix">
    <div id="marketmenu">
        <ul>
            <li><span class="innerli leftish">1st<div class="menudrop"></div></span></li>
            <li><span class="innerli">2nd<div class="menudrop"></div></span></li>
            <li><span class="innerli">3rd<div class="menudrop"></div></span></li>
            <li><span class="innerli">4th<div class="menudrop"></div></span></li>
            <li><span class="innerli">5th<div class="menudrop"></div></span></li>
            <li><span class="innerli rightish">6th<div class="menudrop last"></div></span></li>
        </ul>           
    </div>  
</div>
```

**css**

```
#marketmenu ul{
    cursor: pointer;
}


#marketmenu ul li{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer !important;
    z-index: inherit;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    width: 15%;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    background: black;
    /*
    outline: 2px solid black;
    */

}

.innerli{
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 88%;
    width: 98%;
    margin: 1%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    background-color: white;
    padding-top: 6%;
}

.leftish{
    margin-left: 2.5%;
}

.rightish{
    width: 96%;
}


#marketmenu ul li div {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 98%;
    width: 596.5%;
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 200px;
    opacity: 0;
    background: black;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 9;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    transition: all .3s ease .15s;

}

#marketmenu ul li:first-child div {

}   

#marketmenu ul li:nth-child(2) div {
    margin-left: -100%; 

}

#marketmenu ul li:nth-child(3) div {
    margin-left: -200%; 
}

#marketmenu ul li:nth-child(4) div {
    margin-left: -300%; 
}

#marketmenu ul li:nth-child(5) div {
    margin-left: -400%; 
}

#marketmenu ul li:nth-child(6) div {
    margin-left: -500%; 
    padding-top: 2px;
}


#marketmenu ul li:hover div {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    overflow: visible;
}

.market_navigation{

        position: relative;
        z-index: 40;
        width: 70%;
        margin-left: 30%;
        height: 40px;
        background: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the last li item, add a class of "last":

```
<ul>
    <li>one<div class="menudrop"></div></li>
    <li>two<div class="menudrop"></div></li>
    <li>three<div class="menudrop"></div></li>
    <li>four<div class="menudrop"></div></li>
    <li>five<div class="menudrop"></div></li>
    <li class="last">six<div class="menudrop"></div></li>
</ul>
```

Then change the CSS for the menudrop class from outline to border:

```
#marketmenu ul li{
  display: block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer !important;
  z-index: inherit;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  width: 15%;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

And add the following CSS for the "last" class

```
li.last{
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: hi mate, it does solve the border issue but its not responsive, i.e. when i resize the window the hidden div shrinks slightly compared to the entire menu

Comment: You could add box-sizing to your CSS with border-box as the value:     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;

Comment: David, it looks like the hidden black div is already smaller than the width of the menu before you resize the window.  Do you want the hidden div to be the same width as the menu?

Comment: hi mate, no the slight difference is ok, the issue is the proportion changes when the screen is resized, its not much but it is noticeable. Box sizing should work but the proportions still change. But as a fall back i might use it as a firefox hack and quite a few media queries :(